# Disadvantage of lazy closure executed property over constant?

Tags: swift, swift2, lazy-initialization

I realize there are benefits to lazy self-executed closure properties, such as being able to reference `self`. However, if not using `self`, what are the disadvantages of doing this:

```
 lazy var greeting: String = {
    return "Hello, there!"
 }()
```

As opposed to a constant like this:

```
let greeting = "Hello, there!"
```

Besides constants being a shorter syntax, they both seem to do the same thing (immutable). What are the underlying disadvantages, if any, to using the lazy self-executed property over the constant, or anything different?

Comment: Lazy variables aren't immutable – you can still assign to them like normal read-write properties. It's only the initial value that's created by the closure.

Comment: And you can simply do a lot more work inside the block then just create an instance - you can for example create a label, set its color and background, add it to `self.view` and then return that label.

Comment: Right, its much more powerful, so why not use it all the time even when not needed, out of curiosity on a technical/mechanical level?